# como crear un hash de hashes en perl

Tags: hash, perl, enlace

Les agradeceré su gran apoyo, porque me encuentro generando un **HASH de HASHES** de acuerdo a:

https://www.solvetic.com/topic/2045-hash-de-hashes-perl/

Ya lo generé pero no lo logro imprimir. Por favor, ¿me pueden ayudar a mostrarlo?

Les comento que estoy haciendo referencia a

```
use Data::Dumper
```

Cordiales saludos y respetos para ustedes.

Comment: Que has intentado?, pon un ejemplo mínimo verificable que hayas intentado para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte, aquí las preguntas que no muestran algún intento no son bien recibidas y terminan por ser cerradas, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que sea necesario para entender tu problema, date una vuelta por el [tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Lo tienes explicado en la propia documentación de Perl. En tu ordenador (si está instalado, claro), ejecuta

```
perldoc perldsc
```

Aquí lo tienes traducido al español:
https://github.com/perldocES/perldoc-es/blob/master/pod/translated/perldsc.pod#acceso-e-impresi%C3%B3n-de-un-hash-de-hashes

Comment: ENORMES GRACIAS